# How to stop my laptop from throttling my CPU?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, power-management

I have an AMD TL-60 mobile processor.  I've noticed that often when I watch videos, I get a really jerky playback.  I can fix it if I run the following command:

```
echo 2000000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
echo 2000000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq
```

For some reason, these values get set to 800000..even though I'm using the CPU to play video.  The script helps the video playback for a while and then things go bad until I run the script again.

It appears that my laptop is a hippie and is trying to save power at the expense of being useful.  I turn it off when I am not using it, but when I do have it on, I need to actually do stuff.  How do I properly indoctrinate my laptop to always run at full speed?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.

Comment: Should be on Superuser.com

Comment: does throttling happen when plugged when on AC adapter?

Comment: Turn off all cool & quiet features in the BIOS

Comment: AC adapter is plugged in at all times.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it.  I ran the following command:

`echo performance > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

And then the two other commands in my original question.  It seems to work fine until I sleep the laptop.  I'm wondering if the scaling governor was really set to `rick_perry`.